# How can I stop Resharper from altering refactored code?

Tags: c#, resharper

I have just started using Resharper. It shows a red squiggly line under the name of the mvc view to be returned:

[View name with squiggly name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xy42x.png)

One of the suggestions is to use interpolation:

[Suggestions for correction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DV0t.png)

The squiggly line disappears when selecting the interpolation suggestion:

[View name without squiggly line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Or7qY.png)

When I then use Code Cleanup, the interpolation disappears and the squiggly line is back again. In the Resharper options I have selected 'Don't analyse verbatim strings' under Code Editing, C#, Localization, but this does not make any difference.

I don't like seeing squiggly lines, because then I think I have to take action.

Is there a way to stop Resharper to alter code which has already been corrected by using Resharper suggestions?

Comment: Ok, also new to Stack Overflow. I thought I just copied pictures instead of url's to pictures. Gonna rectify that.

Comment: Have you tried removing the parameter name: `viewName`?

Comment: @JowJoris: Yes, I started off without the viewName, and the squiggly line was already there.

Comment: have you also tried creating a `string` variable like `string viewName = "Error";` and used the variable as parameter?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. And that does work, no more squiggly lines. However, then I have to use an extra line of code before all return statements. I don't think that adds readability. It seems more like a workaround.

Comment: See the docs [Ignore parts of the code](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Ignore_Parts_of_Code.html)

Comment: r# sometimes goes into some invalid state, I would suggest to [clean the cache](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Configuring_Caches_Location.html#cleanup). It might not help, but is an easy thing to try.

Comment: Cleaning the cache, good suggestion, but unfortunately did not help.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't an error. It's an [ASP.NET MVC specific R# feature](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Web_Development__ASP.NET_MVC.html).
This highlighting shows a link to a razor page. You can navigate to the page via <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd>.

To disable this feature open: ReSharper → Options → Environment → Products & Features, uncheck Web Languages.